# Distribute high chart over pages while print in IE9

Tags: asp.net, printing, highcharts, internet-explorer-9

i m very much new to High charts. Here is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/cFhBV/

Basically, there are two charts. When i give the print command from the browser, what i need is first chart should be printed and then immediately the second chart should follow (i.e if there is space left after printing the first chart it should not be left blank. The next chart should appear in that space and if the second chart cannot fully accommodate in that space, the remainder of it should go to the next page) .

Now this works fine in Chrome. But IE9 shows a different behavior. How do i get it to work in IE9.

Following is the javascript code

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit Consumption 1'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fruit eaten'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'A',
                    data: [1, 0, 4]
                }, {
                    name: 'B',
                    data: [5, 7, 3]
                },
                {
                    name: 'C',
                    data: [3, 0, 3]
                },
                {
                    name: 'D',
                    data: [2, 1, 2]
                },
                {
                    name: 'E',
                    data: [4, 5, 1]
                },
                {
                    name: 'F',
                    data: [6, 1, 3]
                },
                {
                    name: 'G',
                    data: [2, 6, 5]
                },
                {
                    name: 'H',
                    data: [7, 2, 3]
                },
                {
                    name: 'I',
                    data: [1, 0, 4]
                },
                {
                    name: 'J',
                    data: [7, 6, 6]
                },
                {
                    name: 'K',
                    data: [1, 8, 5]
                },
                {
                    name: 'L',
                    data: [7, 2, 1]
                }]
            });

            $('#container2').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit Consumption 2'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges', 'Mangoes', 'Grapes', 'Guava', 'Jackfruit','Papaya']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fruit eaten'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'A',
                    data: [1, 0, 4, 4, 6, 2, 7, 3]
                }, {
                    name: 'B',
                    data: [1, 0, 3, 7, 1, 1, 5, 1]
                },
                {
                    name: 'C',
                    data: [1, 3, 3, 7, 1, 5, 5, 1]
                },
                {
                    name: 'D',
                    data: [1, 4, 3, 7, 7, 1, 5, 1]
                },
                {
                    name: 'E',
                    data: [1, 1, 3, 3, 6, 1, 5, 1]
                }]
            });
        });
    });
```

And Html

```
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="container" style="width:900px; height:900px" >

</div>

<div id="container2" style="width:900px; height: 900px " >

</div>        
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts use default javascript print function, not our custom implementation, so I advice to prepare your own print function and add custom button in the exporting menu.